# Set Content appends to other files

Tags: powershell

I am trying to update all html files in a folder with a value of google in it, and change it to yahoo.

The code below appears to be updating the value but all the contents of the html files are combined instead of just updating 1 file at a time.

```
$file = "C:\test\*.html"
$content = (Get-Content -Path $file -ReadCount 0).Replace('google','yahoo')
Set-Content -Path $file -Value $content -Encoding Unicode
```

Before I run the powershell script, the html files looks like this:

**first.html**

```
<h1>First HTML</h1>
<a href="google.com">google</a>
<a href="google1.com">google</a>
<a href="google2.com">google</a>
```

**second.html**

```
<h1>Second HTML</h1>
<a href="google.com">google</a>
<a href="google1.com">google</a>
<a href="google2.com">google</a>
```

But after running the script, the files will now look like this:

**first.html**

```
<h1>Second HTML</h1>
<a href="yahoo.com">yahoo</a>
<a href="yahoo1.com">yahoo</a>
<a href="yahoo2.com">yahoo</a>
<h1>First HTML</h1>
<a href="yahoo.com">yahoo</a>
<a href="yahoo1.com">yahoo</a>
<a href="yahoo2.com">yahoo</a>
```

**second.html**

```
<h1>Second HTML</h1>
<a href="yahoo.com">yahoo</a>
<a href="yahoo1.com">yahoo</a>
<a href="yahoo2.com">yahoo</a>
<h1>First HTML</h1>
<a href="yahoo.com">yahoo</a>
<a href="yahoo1.com">yahoo</a>
<a href="yahoo2.com">yahoo</a>
```

Appreciate if someone could help me with this, TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Get-Item` or `Get-ChildItem` to discover the files, then do the replacement on one file at a time:

```
$file = "C:\test\*.html"
Get-Item -Path $file |ForEach-Object {
  $content = (Get-Content -LiteralPath $_.FullName -ReadCount 0).Replace('google','yahoo')    
  Set-Content -Path $_.FullName -Value $content -Encoding Unicode
}
```